# Android WebView display Full HD html

Tags: android, html, webview, screen-resolution

I want to display an HD html (fixed width and height set to 1920x1080px) file in a WebView.

Everything works fine on my samsung s2 and s4, but I want to run the app on a chinese android media player the website is shown bigger than the screen (with scrollbars).

I tried the following:

In my html file I set:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
```

This doesn't take any effect. So I tried setting the `width=1920` but still the same.

I tried adding this to the WebView:

```
WebSettings settings = myView.getSettings();
settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
settings.setUseWideViewPort(true);
settings.setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
```

Still no effect.

I also checked the display settings on the device but it's set to standard 1080p.

Any ideas?
Thanks.

Comment: Did you manage to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Add meta tag to html page and specify viewport sizes:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="height=1080, width=1920, user-scalable=no" />
```

It's example.
You can find more info in [Android docs](https://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/targeting.html#ViewportDensity)